# $X$ and $Y$ Random Variables Same Distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with the same distribution (their CDF's are the same), is it true that $P(X \in A) = P'(Y \in A)$ for any Borel set $A$?  I was reading a theorem in Durrett and it seemed to indicate this (at least for $A$ with induced measure $0$).  Clearly its true for $A$ of the form ($-\infty, a$] but I am not sure how to prove it for a general Borel set.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is immediate from uniqueness of extensions. Finite disjoint unions of intervals of the type $(a,b]$ form a field which generates the Borel sigma field, so if two measures agree on this field they agree on all Borel sets.